# Structure map throws Error code 202 exceptions unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap

So basically I am using structure map DI container. application type is ASP.NET MVC 4. I am registering the type mapping in the constructor of MvcApplication (global.asax), then I am using custom Controller factory to provide the types I need, but the thing is once in maybe 100-200 request the structure maps fails and throws exception saying `Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily`. I have session state off so the multiple concurrent request are available for single user. One of my the page in my application is drawn dynamically, this page contains like 100-150 images which are return by one the actions in my application, so when that page is being loaded one or may be two pictures in 4-5 request fail to load. and the reason is that when I am retrieving types to path them to controller structure map throws exception at me saying there is no default type for `IMyService`. in every other place, I mean application, it seems to work perfectly. I am not registering type mappings in `Application_Start` because in the `MvcApplication` itself I need to retrieve some of those registered instances.

Comment: Show some registration code.  Also, if you don't register on startup, where (and when) do you register?  Sounds to me like you might be registering more than once?

Comment: yes basically I am registering more than once. Would that create any problem ? I'm registering in MvcApplication's constructor which can be  reused or constructed. so yes registration code executes more than once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, I will make my best guess as to what is happening.

Since you are registering more than once, and you are doing it in the MvcApplication constructor, if two different instances of MvcApplication are handling requests in parallel (which can happen), you can have InstanceA resolving a service while InstanceB is removing and registering services from the container.  When this happens, dependency resolution fails because the container does have what InstanceA is looking for (yet).

Registration is a one-time task that is generally done at system startup (Application_Start).  There are exceptions, but they are very rare.

If you need to resolve dependencies in the MvcApplication, make sure this is only happening after Application_Start has finished registration.

Comment: what about wcf ? I have wcf application in my solution to. So I have some kind of base service which is registering types in the constructor and retrieving them right after it. What you said above can happen in this case as well right ?

Comment: Yes.  Again, the idea is to register once at start-up, and never register again except in rare exceptions.